# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "client_secret", setupIntent is undefined - Stripe API | ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Been spinning my wheels on not being able to access the client_secret I've found a number of other posts with solutions, but so far none have proven to be helpful upon following them. When deleting a saved card I keep getting the following error. "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "client_secret", setupIntent is undefined"

React app:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { fetchFromAPI } from '../../../helpers';
import { message } from "antd";

const CreditCardInfo = ({ uId }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  console.log(stripe, "stripe");
  const elements = useElements();
  const [cardError, setCardError] = useState(null);
  const [setupIntent, setSetupIntent] = useState();
  const [cardComplete, setCardComplete] = useState([]); //Same as wallet
  // const [wallet, setWallet] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCardDetails();
  }, [uId]);


  const createSetupIntent = async (event) => {
    const si = await fetchFromAPI('wallet');
    setSetupIntent(si);
  };

  // Handle the submission of card details
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    // Confirm Card Setup
    const {
      setupIntent: updatedSetupIntent,
      error,
    } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret, {
      payment_method: { card: cardElement },
    });

    if (error) {
      alert(error.message);
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      setSetupIntent(updatedSetupIntent);
      await getCardDetails();
      alert('Success! Card added to your wallet');
    }
  };

  const getCardDetails = async () => { //Same as getWallet
    if (uId) {
      const paymentMethods = await fetchFromAPI('wallet', { method: 'GET' });
      setCardComplete(paymentMethods);
    }
  };

  const DeleteSavedCard = async () => {
    const cardId = cardComplete.cardId;
    const uId = localStorage.getItem("USERID");
  
    try {
      const response = await fetchFromAPI('deleteCard', {
        method: 'GET',
        body: JSON.stringify({ cardId, uId })
      });
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log('This is a result:' + result);
      if (response.ok) {
        // Card deleted successfully
        console.log('Card deleted successfully');
  
        // Optionally, you can perform additional actions after card deletion
      } else {
        // Handle error if card deletion failed
        console.error('Card deletion failed:', result.error.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any other errors
      console.error('An error occurred:', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit } className="well">
      <CardElement />
      {cardError && (
        <div className="card-error" role="alert">
          {cardError}
        </div>
      )}
      <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe || !cardComplete} onClick={createSetupIntent}>
        Add Card
      </button>

      <div>
        <p>Prevous Payment Methods</p>
          {cardComplete.map((paymentSource) => (
                    <CreditCard key={paymentSource.id} card={paymentSource.card} />
                    ))}
                  </div>
      
    </form>
    
  );

  function CreditCard(props) {
    
    const { last4, brand, exp_month, exp_year } = props.card;
    return (
      
        <p className="TEST">{brand} **** **** **** {last4} expires {exp_month}/{exp_year} <button onClick={DeleteSavedCard}>Delete</button></p>
    );
  }

};

export default CreditCardInfo;
```

API:

```
// EXPRESS API
import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { createSetupIntent, listPaymentMethods } from './customers';
import { createStripeCheckoutSession } from './checkout';


export const app = express();


app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());


// Sets rawBody for webhook handling
app.use(
    express.json({
      verify: (req, res, buffer) => (req['rawBody'] = buffer),
    })
);


app.use(decodeJWT);

/**
 * Decodes the JSON Web Token sent via the frontend app
 * Makes the currentUser (firebase) data available on the body.
 */
async function decodeJWT(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    if (req.headers?.authorization?.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  
      try {
        const decodedToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
        req['currentUser'] = decodedToken;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    next();
}

/**
 * Throws an error if the currentUser does not exist on the request
 */
function validateUser(req: Request) {
    const user = req['currentUser'];
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error(
        'You must be logged in to make this request. i.e Authroization: Bearer <token>'
      );
    }
  
    return user;
}

/**
 * Checkouts
 */
app.post(
    '/Booking/',
    runAsync(async ({ body }: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.send(await createStripeCheckoutSession(body.line_items));
    })
);

/**
 * Customers and Setup Intents
 */

// Save a card on the customer record with a SetupIntent
app.post(
    '/wallet',
    runAsync(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const user = validateUser(req);
      const setupIntent = await createSetupIntent(user.uid);
      res.send(setupIntent);
    })
);
  
  // Retrieve all cards attached to a customer
  app.get(
    '/wallet',
    runAsync(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const user = validateUser(req);

      const wallet = await listPaymentMethods(user.uid);
      res.send(wallet.data);
    })
);

  // Delete card attached to a customer

  app.post("/deleteCard", 
    runAsync( async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    console.log("\n\n Body Passed:", req.body);   
    const { uId, cardId } = req.body;
    const user = validateUser(req);
    const cardId  = req.body;
    if (!cardId || user.uId) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        Error: "CardId is required to delete Card",
      });
    }
    try {
      const user = validateUser(req);
      const deleteCard = await user.customers.deleteSource(user.uId, cardId);
      return res.status(200).send(deleteCard);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        Error: "Error deleting card",
      });
    }
  
  })
  
  );


function runAsync(callback: Function) {
    return(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
      callback(req, res, next).catch(next);
    };
}
```

I followed another stackoverflow post that suggested I change the confrimCardSetup function to the following, but I wasn't able to get it to work, it's also pretty much the same way I have my function currently.

```
stripe.confirmCardSetup(
  clientSecret,
  {
    payment_method: {
      card: cardElement,
    },
  }
)
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see what specific line of code is throwing this error? The error makes it sound like you are calling the `stripe.confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret` when `setupIntent` is null.

Comment: I'm pretty sure from what I've been able to debug so far that it's coming from that line, but I'm still in the dark as to what's causing it to be null. Because the code works when adding and saving a card to a customer via Stripe, but it will still throw the uncaught error I shared above. Both when adding and deleting a card. Still working on debugging though too. Was hoping to get pointed in a direction for debugging this.